# Show summary of proposal progress in tool-tip of progress bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

Just a small feature request for Area 51 - when you're looking at a list of proposals (say http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=followed or on user pages) could the yellow-blue progress bars have a hover tool-tip saying something like '90% commitment'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been implemented. Thanks for the suggestion.